# Is there any way to make the ubuntu icon launch Kupfer instead of the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, gnome-do, synapse, kupfer

I find programs like [Kupfer](http://engla.github.io/kupfer/), [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project), [Gnome-do](http://do.cooperteam.net/), and [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) much quicker, more task-oriented, and generally more useful than the unity dash. I use the shortcut keys: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to launch Kupfer, but I would also like to use the big friendly button:

[image: Ubuntu Dash Icon: Big Friendly Button (bfb)]

Is there any way to edit a .desktop file or something? Or is it hard-coded? At the very least, can I remove it completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm pretty sure neither of those things are possible, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much. I have set the launcher to auto-hide with compizconfig-settings-manager, and activate with the top corner. Essentially, I never have to see it. I have also installed Plank Dock, which allows the functionality I described in the question. As a bonus, Plank auto-hides and reveals much easier than the unity launcher.

Comment: You might want to turn the sensitivity of the autohide all the way down so you can't accidentally activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://maximebf.com/blog/2012/07/replace-ubuntu-dash-with-synapse/#.VMcMU4E76rU

It tells you how to replace dash with synapse using compiz

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I'm looking for.